# Silverstripe 4.4 Browse Files in CMS / Safari / Mac / OS 10.14

Tags: macos, file, file-upload, safari, silverstripe

How can i fix this problem?

The Browse - Button in SS 4.4 (CMS / Files  / Upload - Button) does not work
when using Safari 14.0.1 on Mac OS 10.14.

The popup - window to select files for upload does not appear.
No javascript errors, no PHP errors.

Works fine on Mac with Firefox.
From the SS - docs (v4):

> CMS browser requirements#
>
> SilverStripe CMS supports the following web browsers:
>
> Google Chrome Internet Explorer 11 Microsoft Edge Mozilla Firefox We
> aim to provide satisfactory experiences in Apple Safari. SilverStripe
> CMS works well across Windows, Linux, and Mac operating systems.

Can this problem be solved?
Thanks.

Comment: I have tested this on Safari 14 on Silverstripe 4.4 from a plain install of `silverstripe/recipe-cms:4.4.7`. The Upload button works correctly for me. I would recommend setting up a plain install of Silverstripe cms and checking that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue with Safari 14.0.1 that it's broken on Mojave but not on Catalina or Big Sur.
Download the Mojave installer from the App Store, reinstall Mojave and then upgrade everything (security patches, etc) except Safari 14.0.1. Keep remain with the Safari 14.0.0. You will be fine..

Cheers....